# how to import python modules from different packages

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I have a python application which contains unittest as well. Below is my file structure

```
├── src
│   ├── common
│   │    ├──constants.py
│   │    └──configs.py
│   ├── utils
│   │    ├──module1.py
│   │    └──module2.py
│   └── service
│   │     ├──module3.py
│   │     └──module4.py
│   └── main.py
├── test
│   ├── utils
│   │    ├──test_module1.py
│   │    └──test_module2.py
```

utils/module1.py contain

```
# module1.py
from common.constants import LOG_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT
...
```

test_module1.py contain

```
# test_module1.py
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
from src.utils.module1 import filter_file
from unittest import TestCase, main, mock
```

and when i run below code from root below exception occurs.

```
$- python3 test/utils/test_module1.py
$- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

I am using a linux machine. It will work when i try to add a "src." before every module import inside module1.py. But i don't want to change the code inside src because i have dockerized it. Please suggest your idea.

Comment: What happens if  you add `sys.path.append("./src")` after the `sys.path.append` you already have ?

Comment: wow. that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the directory containing `test` and `src` to `sys.path`, then accessing `topleveldir/src/utils/module1.py` with `src.utils.module1`. That module tries to import the file `topleveldir/common/constants.py`, but the file is actually located at `topleveldir/src/common/constants.py` - this *must* give a `ModuleNotFound` error. Change `sys.path.append(".")` to `sys.path.append("./src")` and remove the `src.` from the import below that, and it should work fine.